# Batchfile command output into file with date and time in its name

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, path

I need to save the data of a java program into a file. The problem is, it returns a "**The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect**" error when I add the **%DATE% and %TIME%** variables into the filename. Without the date time variables it works fine.

As well I need to output the result into the console **and** the file. As far as I have seen, there is no direct possibility to do so. Workaround: I'm just reading the file again into the console. When doing that **with the date time** variable, **I get the same error.**

```
set datetime="%DATE%-%TIME%"

java -Xmx1024m -jar org.hl7.fhir.validator.jar generated.json  -version 4.0.1 -ig hl7.fhir.uv.livd > "errlog/%datetime%.log"

type "%CD%\errlog\%datetime%.log"
```

*I never write batch files so could be a very "stupid" problem. Thanks in advance!*

Comment: `%DATE%` has `/` (slashes) in it, which are not valid in a filename.  You need to replace the slashes with another character.

Comment: Yeah i just realized that too. I have an european format with "hh:mm:ss.ms" and ":" are not allowed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line instead:

```
set datetime="%DATE:/=-%-%TIME::=_%"
```